# Understanding 遺伝子とは関わりない所で手に入れた何か

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Kaguya-sama ch. 297

[image]

> **遺伝子とは関わりない所で手に入れた何か**に人が惹かれることもあるだろう

I have trouble understanding the meaning of the bold part, especially 所 and 手に入れた何か.

遺伝子とは関わりない所で seems to mean during situations where genetics are not related (?). Does 所 mean situation?

Lastly, does 手に入れた何か mean something that people obtained in situations where genetics are not related?

It is hard for me to see what the author is trying to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation

> something that people obtained in situations where genetics are not related?

is fine, except perhaps more literally *places* rather than *situations*.

The first phrase (人が遺伝子交換をする為に...) suggests that (the author thinks) people are attracted by each other at the genetic level. Then, the sentence in question essentially says genes are not everything (*one may be attracted by something that a person obtained not from genes = something that has nothing to do with genes*)